# Fetch each data from LOOP

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am sending some reward to every user from my struct in loop.  After I send the reward I will update amount and fees in another table to show it further.  Can
I send this data (every transaction) to my frontend?

Answer (score 0):

If you were storing a list of transactions in the smart contract, you could query that from your frontend. If you were doing this with a lot of transactions though you would end up paying quite big gas fees for doing it.

Can you post any of the code you have already?

Comment: Will it charge me big gas fees if I am transferring bnb?

Comment: BNB (assuming you're on the binance smart chain of course) is cheaper to transfer than ERC20/BEP20 tokens, but you'll pay lots of gas because you're doing multiple transactions (1 for each wallet you have to send rewards to). Id love to have the code too as there's no real way to answer your question without it, but the way i see it is that you want to create an event that records the amount of tokens send to each wallet each time your loop iterates, and then listen to it on your frontend (so it updates automatically, without having to manually query it)

Comment: Though the fees will increase but it will not bigger than amount I am transferring. I think. Isn't it? Could it be bigger than amount I transfer?

Comment: Of course it can, its actually totally unrelated to the amount you transfer. The price for sending 1 million tokens and 0.0001 tokens is the same (21000 gas, assuming you're sending to a wallet, a little more if you're sending to a contract)

Comment: It's not a token. New User deposit amount to contract address and on certain criteria contract sends reward to all users on their wallet address, so it's wallet to wallet.

Comment: So the max would be 21000 gas and not more than that. Correct?